# How to create a list of lists of all the n'th characters from a list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a list that contains multiple strings created from a FASTA format file.
The list is like this:

```
data = ['ATCCAGCT', 'GGGCAACT', 'ATGGATCT', 'AAGCAACC', 'TTGGAACT', 'ATGCCATT', 'ATGGCACT']
```

I want to get the characters at the first index of all the strings in the list and transfer them to another list and I do it like this:

```
list1 = []
z = 0
while x < len(data):
    list1.append(((data[x])[z]))
    x += 1
```

Now that I have the first index, how do I do that for every index of all the strings? Assuming they are all the same length.

Comment: Are you looking for `list1 = [s[0] for s in data]`?

Comment: What are you doing with all those brackets in `list1.append(((data[x])[z]))`??

Comment: I agree with mkrieger1, list comprehensions are way easier to read and write. Saves 4 lines.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
data = ['ATCCAGCT', 'GGGCAACT', 'ATGGATCT', 'AAGCAACC', 'TTGGAACT', 'ATGCCATT', 'ATGGCACT']

mydict = {}

for position in range(len(data[0])):
    mydict[str(position)] = []

for seq in data:
    for position, nucleotide in enumerate(seq):
        mydict[str(position)].append(nucleotide)

for position in mydict.keys():
    print (position,mydict[position],"".join(mydict[position]))
```

Output:

```
0 ['A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A'] AGAATAA
1 ['T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T'] TGTATTT
2 ['C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G'] CGGGGGG
3 ['C', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G'] CCGCGCG
4 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'] AAAAACC
5 ['G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'] GATAAAA
6 ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'C'] CCCCCTC
7 ['T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T'] TTTCTTT
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks! One more thing, how can I assign the created list to a variable?

Comment: thanks! You can accept the answer :). A variable you mean? There is the dict? Otherwise just do list_at_position = mydict[str(position)].copy()

Comment: Oh right! I'm pretty new to programming sorry ahahah. Btw how do I accept your answer?

Comment: just click on the grey tick top left of my answer. It will turn green :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If **all your strings are of same length**, you can **use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)** to achieve this:

```
>>> data = ['ATCCAGCT', 'GGGCAACT', 'ATGGATCT', 'AAGCAACC', 'TTGGAACT', 'ATGCCATT', 'ATGGCACT']
>>> my_lists = zip(*data)

>>> my_lists[0]  # chars from `0`th index of each string
('A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A')

>>> my_lists[1]  # chars from `1`st index of each string
('T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T')

# ... so on
```

If you want each of these lists stored in separate variables, then you can also unpack these like:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h  = zip(*data)

# where:
# a = ('A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A') ## chars from `0`th index 
# b = ('T', 'G', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T') ## chars from `1`st index
```

---

In case **your strings are of different length**, you can **use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)** in Python 3 (or [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2) as:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest  # In Python 3
# OR, from itertools import izip_longest  # In Python 2  
                                  
>>> my_list = ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'j']

>>> list(zip_longest(*my_list, fillvalue=''))
[('a', 'd', 'f', 'j'), ('b', 'e', 'g', ''), ('c', '', 'h', ''), ('', '', 'i', '')]
```

Skipping `fillvalue` param in above example will fill the empty elements with `None` like this:

```
[('a', 'd', 'f', 'j'), ('b', 'e', 'g', None), ('c', None, 'h', None), (None, None, 'i', None)]
```

Comment: What if they are really long? how can I do that? Edit: the strings

Comment: @sickleox2 what is really long ?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri the strings, 60 or more indexes

Comment: that's fine too. it'll work with above code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they all have the same length, you can zip the string.
The first string in the result contains all the first chars, the second all the seconds, etc

```
>>> res = ["".join(el) for el in zip(*data)]
>>> res
['AGAATAA', 'TGTATTT', 'CGGGGGG', 'CCGCGCG', 'AAAAACC', 'GATAAAA', 'CCCCCTC', 'TTTCTTT']
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is a for loop that loops for every item in the list. This is how I would do it:

```python
data = ['ATCCAGCT', 'GGGCAACT', 'ATGGATCT', 'AAGCAACC', 'TTGGAACT', 'ATGCCATT', 'ATGGCACT']
first_index = []

for i in data:
    first_index.append(i[0])

print(first_index)
```

This outputs a list which looks like this:

`['A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A']`

Answer (score 0):

So, I've take your question to mean getting the first letter of each string in the `data`.
(`A`TCCAGCT).

The way I would do it is:

```py
data = ['.', '..', '...'] # Ur values
list1 = [] # empty list
for x in data: # for each entry
  list1.append(x[0]) # add the first letter
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension.  If you want to use a loop, then deconstruct this to the loop form.  You went to a lot of indirect effort in your posted code.

```
first = [seq[0] for seq in data]
```